# error compling php5 with gd for ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, php, gd

I need the `imageantialias()` to work on the server I built. I have complied PHP before but for some reason I can't do it any more.  I ran these steps to try:

1. `apt-get source php5`
2. `apt-get build-dep php5`
3. `cd php5-*`
4. `nano debian/rules`
5. find this line `--with-gd=shared,/usr --enable-gd-native-ttf \` and remove `,/usr`
6. save and exit
7. `nano debian/setup_mysql.sh`
8. search for `Start the daemon`
9. add `–user=root` after the `mysqld`
10. save and exit
11. `dpkg-buildpackage –rfakeroot -us –uc -d`

then it runs for a long time and then it ends here:

```
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/php5-5.3.10/cgi-build'
    sed -i -e 's/-d output_buffering=1 -d open_basedir="" -d safe_mode=0/-d output_buffering=1 -d open_basedir="" -d safe_mode=0 -d memory_limit="-1"/' \
           /usr/src/php5-5.3.10/pear-build/usr/bin/pear && \
    sed -i -e 's/-d output_buffering=1 -d safe_mode=0/-d output_buffering=1 -d open_basedir="" -d safe_mode=0 -d memory_limit="-1"/' \
           /usr/src/php5-5.3.10/pear-build/usr/bin/pecl && \
    sed -i -e 's/-d memory_limit="-1"//' \
           -e 's/-d output_buffering=1 -d open_basedir="" -d safe_mode=0/-d output_buffering=1 -d open_basedir="" -d safe_mode=0 -d memory_limit="-1"/' \
           /usr/src/php5-5.3.10/pear-build/usr/bin/peardev
    sed -i -re "s#('PEAR_CONFIG_SYSCONFDIR', PHP_SYSCONFDIR)#\1 . '/pear'#" /usr/src/php5-5.3.10/pear-build/usr/share/php/PEAR/Config.php
    patch -s -d /usr/src/php5-5.3.10/pear-build/usr/share/php/ -p1 -i /usr/src/php5-5.3.10/debian/patches/PEAR-Builder-print-info-about-php5-dev.patch
    touch build-pear-stamp
    mkdir -p temp_session_store
    # start our own mysql server for the tests
    /bin/sh debian/setup-mysql.sh 2963 /usr/src/php5-5.3.10/mysql_db
make: *** [test-results.txt] Error 1
    dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
```

I tried it without modifying the `setup-mysql.sh` as well but the same thing happens. I'm not really sure why this isn't working. I know the last time I did this I had a lot of trouble. Also I've tried this on two separate 12.04 servers with the same problem.

Comment: there are some of the things I've looked up http://mapopa.blogspot.com/2012/06/php-gd-bundled-compilation-instructions.html

Comment: Why are you going to all this trouble? You could just install Red Hat/CentOS and have it working in as long as it takes to download the `php-gd` package.

Comment: Can you explain why you remove `,/usr` from the `--with-gd=shared` option? what is the purpose?

Comment: I use ubuntu for the most part because it just works for me. I have to remove the /usr part I think because it points the the package that ubuntu supplies and that doesn't include the imageantialias() function, I need to use the one that is bundled with php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just thought I'd put this out there for anyone else having this same issue. I had to fix this same problem on a Ubuntu server and [this article](http://ctrl-f5.net/php/building-php-with-bundeled-gd-on-ubuntu/) (credit goes to the person that wrote it) actually covers the solution.

In short:

**The Error:**

```
make: *** [test-results.txt] Error 1
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
```

**The solution (as covered in the above article):**

> This is caused because the mysql server refuses to run under root

```
$ sudo vim debian/setup-mysql.sh
```

> In this file comment the line starting the server, and copy the command, adding the “–user=root” parameter:

```
# Start the daemon
#$mysqld > $datadir/run.log 2>&1 &
#add root user
$mysqld --user=root > $datadir/run.log 2>&1 &
```

**Then finally:**

```
$ sudo dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot
```